# Jenkins build with unity always gets stuck

Tags: unity-game-engine, jenkins

I'm trying to set up a nightly build for my unity project with jenkins, but unity keeps causing issues. 
The build always gets stuck at the same point

`Updating Assets/Attachments/Gun/bot_gun.prefab - GUID: 6b996d754b758c44fbe3b6a825595b5b...
 done. [Time: 38.028000 ms] 
Updating Packages/com.unity.render-pipelines.high-definition/HDRP/RenderPipelineResources/DefaultHDMaterial.mat - GUID: 73c176f402d2c2f4d929aa5da7585d17...`

it works fine until that point, but then just stays there for as long as I let it run. I even let one build run for about 10 hours and it didn't move.

I'm using Unity 2018.2.18f1 with jenkins 2.138.3 and the unity3d plugin 1.3 on Ubuntu 18.04.1

Unity is installed in /opt/Unity3d and all ownership is set to the jenkins user

the command line arguments for unity are

`-quit -batchmode -nographics -logfile -buildLinuxUniversalPlayer ./out/BotEngineer_Linux/BotEngineer.x86`

[Here's the full log](https://cdn.scode.ovh/jenkinslog.txt)

Thanks for reading, it would be great if anyone could help me solve this issue

Comment: `WARNING: No change detected to Editor.log path: '/var/lib/jenkins/.config/unity3d/Editor.log'.
 The unity3d plugin was probably unable to find it in its expected locations (see JENKINS-24265).
 Consider using the -logFile argument to force a known editor.log path or report the issue.` Did you try to use `logFile` (upper case F) instead?

Comment: I'll try that soon, thank you

Comment: it went to the same point, I'll let it run for a while and see if it gets any further, don't think so tho @derHugo

Comment: it didn't do anything in the last 2 hours